# Plotting coloured points in a 2D space

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the 2D phase space of a magnetic pendulum.

I have the different initial conditions x0 et y0 stored in two different lists and the final positions also stored in two different lists.

I would like to plot a map (x0min->x0max & y0min->y0max) where each point is coloured depending on the final position (which is an attractor/magnet).

I have no ideas how to create this map and how to colour points with conditions, someone could help me?

Have a nice day

Matteo

Ps : here is my code

```
(*Parameters*)
P = 0.2;  
Q = 0.1; 
h = 0.5;

n = 2; (*Magnet number*)
R = {10,10};(*Magnet intensity*)
X = {1,-1}; (*Magnet x position*)
Y = {0,0}; (*Magnet y position*)
tf = 30; (*time of simulation*)

(*results storage*)
cix = {}; (*ci=initial condition*)
ciy = {};
resultx = {};
resulty = {};

(*Fixed initial condition*)
vx0 = 0;
vy0 = 0;

For[i = -2, i <= 2, i += 0.1,
 For[j = -2, j <= 2, j += 0.1,
  x0 = i;
  y0 = j;

  (*Differential equations of the magnetic pendulum*)
  sol = NDSolve[{
     x''[t] + P*x'[t] + Q*x[t] + 
       Sum[(R[[i]]*(x[t] - 
           X[[i]]))/(((X[[i]] - x[t])^2) + ((Y[[i]] - 
               y[t])^2) + (h^2))^3, {i, n}] == 0,
     y''[t] + P*y'[t] + Q*y[t] + 
       Sum[(R[[i]]*(y[t] - 
           Y[[i]]))/(((X[[i]] - x[t])^2) + ((Y[[i]] - 
               y[t])^2) + (h^2))^3, {i, n}] == 0,
     x[0] == x0, y[0] == y0, x'[0] == vx0, y'[0] == vy0},
    {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, tf}];
  (*ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t],y[t]}/.sol],{t,0,tf},
  PlotRange\[Rule]All]*)
  solx[t_] = x[t] /. sol[[1]];
  soly[t_] = y[t] /. sol[[1]];
  AppendTo[cix, x0];
  AppendTo[ciy, y0];
  AppendTo[resultx, solx[tf]];
  AppendTo[resulty, soly[tf]];
  ]]
```

Comment: `Graphics`+`Point`?

Comment: Also, please, post a _minimal_ example. The differential equation has actually nothing to do with your question.